# Independent Bulkification vs Batched Processing

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, batch, bulkification, queueable-apex

I have been acquiring quite a bit of information about how bulkification and batch record processing works in salesforce (bits and pieces - salesforce documentation does not seem exhaustive). While I am starting to get a bit of a grasp on it, I have several points of clarification I need assistance with.

So here is the scenario. I have an invoked flow that runs when a list button is clicked. The very first thing that happens in this flow is that a bulkifiable event happens (in this case, and apex action, but it could also be a get records element, update records element, etc...).

1. If this flow were to be invoked multiple times (either immediately back-to-back by a single user, or from multiple users at the same time), it is my understanding that each invocation of the flow is a separate and independent transaction. As a result, I THINK that salesforce would only bulkify at that first apex action WITHIN each individual flow invocation, but I would like to clarify: Is it possible that salesforce would perform bulkification across the transactions? (So if the flow was invoked 4 times with 50 records in each invocation, would salesforce attempt to run the apex action once will all 200 records in it, or would transaction boundaries keep the bulkification across transactions from happening?)

Now lets say that just prior to the apex action / bulkifiable event, I call a pause element. What this does is that for each of my supposed 4 flow invocations, I now have 4 paused flow interviews (transactions??). I can see this when I pull up the scheduled queue; I have 4 pending jobs waiting to execute. When each job resumes, the pause element would have reset governor limits, and they will each resume at the next element (which is my apex action):

2. It seems that when jobs resume from the scheduled queue after the pause element, that batching DOES occur across transactions. So to clarify, does salesforce bulkify across transactions that are resumed from a scheduled queue? And, are there any special qualifications, such as only batching records based on the user that invoked the flow or something? Also, when the flows continue, even IF salesforce is batching records at bulkifiable elements ACROSS TRANSACTIONS, do the flows maintain any independence? For example, would the flows maintain independent flow variables and context, and simply just batch at the bulkifiable elements?

And lastly, what about queueable apex jobs? Lets say that rather than using a pause element prior to my apex action, I just call the apex action and send records to a queue for processing. That queue invokes a different flow, that has bulkifiable elements in it (get and update record elements).

3. I am of the understanding the queueable apex jobs in salesforce are run as independent transactions; however, if I have several jobs running in parallel, and they each call a flow with bulkifiable events, would salesforce seek to batch records across the queued jobs? Or would the bulkifiable events execute independently for each queued job separately?

I would really appreciate some help here; I have been on a rather long journey trying to learn about the way salesforce works behind-the-scenes, and I have definitely been making progress; these are just several points I am unsure about, and would really appreciable someone's expertise to help clarify. Thanks so much!!

Comment: hey there, i HIGHLY recommend reading this : https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides/trigger-automation#Flow_Bulkification (and the entire article)
I feel lots of your questions will be answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have posted the link to [architect.salesforce](https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides/trigger-automation) that i highly recommend reading.

question 1 :
No bulkification across user.
No bulkification across transactions.
bulkification may happen in same transaction by same user but once again not across transactions.

question 2:
Pause element, basically suspends the transaction to start a new one later. Thus no, no bulkification across paused element (-> No bulkification across transactions.) What you think is bulkification is the fact that it saves the status of the transaction and is able to re-start from there. but believe me, it does not take the element from transaction 1 and transaction 2 and bulkify them together.

Question 3 :
Same as question 1. Separate transaction, separate context, not bulkified together. thus would the bulkifiable events execute independently for each queued job separately.

Comment: Thank you for directing me to that article, and for your answer. Very insightful. However, could you clarify question 2 a bit more? I'm not sure I understand your answer, but to clarify: After several transactions are paused, when they resume and call a bulkifiable event, does salesforce batch these records together across the transactions? Or does the bulkifiable event execute simple for the records in that given transaction?

Comment: i think that what you need to grasp here is that salesforce is multi tenant. Thus the server gets request for execution for your org, but also for other orgs. This is why each transaction is so separated. within a server transaction it does not look at what is contained in other transactions. Thus your bulkification will look into what is happening here and now but not elsewhere. Hence your bulkified event will be called in separate transactions and thus no see eachother. Hope this is little better as an answer